# Using QIODevice::write method add " &#xd; " instead of carriage return

Tags: c++, xml, qt, character-encoding, ascii

In order to replace a part of a XML file, I am using QDomNode class to :

- insert a node before an existing one
- remove a node

But when I do so, I obtain an horrible result : Each line of the node I've add ended with these characters .

````
<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <scene>
    <material>
      <uid>50000006</uid>
      <name>NEW_NODE</name>&#xd;
                            /&#xd;
                          .7&#xd;
               \       , //&#xd;
               |\.--._/|//&#xd;
              /\ ) ) ).'/&#xd;
             /(  \  // /&#xd;
            /(   J`((_/ \&#xd;
           / ) | _\     /&#xd;
          /|)  \  eJ    L&#xd;
         |  \ L \   L   L&#xd;
        /  \  J  `. J   L&#xd;
        |  )   L   \/   \&#xd;
       /  \    J   (\   /&#xd;
       |  \      \   \```&#xd;
   </material>
</scene>
````

I would like to know how to insert a node without these characters at the end of each new line.

Here is my method to insert a new data on my XML File :

```
// ADD A NEW DATA
void ParserIGS::addNewElement(QDomElement element, QDomElement oldElement)
{
  // Insert the new element before the old one
  oldElement.parentNode().insertBefore(element,oldElement);

  // Verify if the new material had an UID child
  QDomNodeList elementNodeList = element.elementsByTagName("uid");
  QDomNode n = oldElement.elementsByTagName("uid").at(0);
  if(elementNodeList.isEmpty()) // Creation of uid tag as firstChild
    element.insertBefore(n, element.firstChild());
  else
    element.replaceChild(n, element.firstChild());
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that seq '&#xd;' is created by default **toString()** method. So, you need to manually do replace like: doc_text.replace( "&#xd;", "" );. 
Link: https://code.google.com/r/pmarinc-tidylib/source/browse/src/Sigil/BookManipulation/XHTMLDoc.cpp?r=57851ba5653f4662fafe6af952265b540c6e16b6

Comment: "Using QIODevice::write…” - where do you use QIODevice::write()? How does the original file look like? What node contents do you actually insert? Do you want to preserve the CRs? If yes, why? If the whitespace and newlines are important, you should probably use xml:space=“preserve”.

Comment: You should provide the code where you create the new element, where the string in the new element is created and added to the element, and how you output the string we see here.

The code you have provided should not cause this to happen.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem. Interesting is: On my side, only after the opening tag (<name>) and the value -  this string appears.

Comment: I have quite similar problem using `insertAfter`. The special sequence `&#xd;` is added (not always) but in some lines... and I don't even see a logic in why those lines are selected...

Comment: The special sequence `&#xd;` is added at the end of lines containing the value for a `textNode` with some white space or tabs... e.g. 
`<span class="InfoSuppTop_intestazione_eng">&#xd;
     Information&#xd;
    </span>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `insertAfter` to insert a `textNode` containing whitespaces.
**It comes out that XML considers four characters to be whitespace**: the carriage return (\r or ch(13)), the linefeed (\n or ch(10)), the tab(\t or ch(9)), and the spacebar (' ' or ch(32)).
In XML characters can be encoded as entities with &#... (similarly to html) and in particular there is an hexadecimal numeric format for entities like this:

```
&#x Hexadecimal number ;
```

For some reason the `toString()` method is encoding carriage return as an xml hexadecimal entity with `&#xd;` which is correct from a formal point of view.
So if you are inserting text nodes with whitespaces, all you have to do is to create elements without whitespaces and after that you can `AddNewElement` and in the end you will see that no `&#xd;` is present